# atom has a strange color in Ruby-ERB(HTML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-editor

[image: strange color]

The Ruby-erb grammar has a strange color after each function with `|group|` variable.
Under `<tbody>` tag `<td>` content's color is gray, here has a strange problem.

[image: if is not group variable, the color is normal]

When I change the variable name, the color becomes normal.

Answer (score 1):

`group` appears to be a reserved word. You'll see the same behavior if you use `ruby`, `source`, or `gem`.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/atom/language-ruby/blob/master/spec/gemfile-spec.coffee), it appears that these words were only intended to be reserved within Gemfiles, so I suspect it may be a bug in the `atom/language-ruby` package.

Until that's fixed, though, your best bet is probably to use a different variable name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response~